# Semantic Issue (Xcode): Mixing declarations and code is incompatible with standards before C99

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, react-native

Getting this error when trying to run the iOS Project from Flutter and Xcode. My Xcode version is 14.3

Comment: You will need to provide some example of the code causing this if you want any help with it.

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister
This is happening due to Xcode 14.3, somehow compiler is not understanding semantics of Obj-C code. Reverting to Xcode 14.2 can work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happening due to Xcode version update to 14.3. May be for some reasons compiler is not understanding the semantics of Obj-c files which are created automatically while working on flutter project.

A workaround and swift solution to this problem is to revert to Xcode 14.2 and it will be working. May be you can also wait for another Xcode update but for now I will say to revert to 14.2 as currently no such solution is available at Apple Forums as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've not dug into this issue all that much, but a few workarounds that just helped me build a large project that was hitting this (Hammerspoon):

- turn off 'Treat Warnings as Errors' (aka -Werror)
- turn off 'Pedantic Warnings' (aka -pedantic)
- turn off '-Weverything'
- and/or add '-Wno-error=declaration-after-statement'

As always your milage may differ, but HTH.